# HTML designer for generating marketing e-mails

Tags: html, email, html-editor, marketing, templating

We would like to send our customers e-mail adverts from our new products every now and then. Our product data is available in one of our databases and the e-mail will be sent using MailChimp (which let's us to store the target email addresses on their server). All we need is the templates designed and generated for every type of e-mail/campaign.

The problem is, MailChimp's online editor would require a lot's of manual effort from us to always manually replace some parts of the template, like switching the products name or the image. However using MailChimp's API it is possible to upload a complete HTML e-mail, so if we had some kind of desktop application, where we design the e-mails and generate new ones, we could integrate it with MailChip in the end.

User designs a template (with variables, like `{{product.name}}`) **-->** Software let's us generate the resulting e-mails using our data (from different sources, mainly SQL) **-->** Either we manually upload the template or make a simple service which uploads the htmls to MailChimp. **-->** MailChimp sends the e-mails to users we registered in some other way.

The software would be used by non-programmers, so It should be some kind of editor, like the old HTML editors (Adobe Dreamweaver), but with strong e-mail templating/generating capabilities.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Feel free to suggest me different approaches of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following setup:

- Upload the products to Wordpress + [WooCommerce](https://hu.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)
- Integrate the shop with [MailChimp for WooCommerce addon](https://mailchimp.com/integrations/woocommerce/)

Mailchimp also has other integrations: https://mailchimp.com/integrations/

This way, we upload the products to WooCommerce and the MailChimp addon (be careful, there are multiple ones you can install, some only sync users. Follow the guide on MailChimp's site. I even needed to manually upload the addon to get it work -> Do not use the WP plugin search) will sync all the product names along with the images to MailChimp. So when we create a campaign, we can insert products easily using the online editor.

Answer (score 1):

Sender tool can help to create own HTML email design for subscribers and send it to your subscribers. You can use segmentation to send different emails for every product or you can use your data and import that. Sender have ease to use drip drop builder and ready-to-use templates.

Sender have integrations with Wordpress + Woocommerce, Magneto or Prestashop, what would make it easier to import data into emails.

Here's link to Sender tool - https://www.sender.net/

Answer (score 0):

One service that may be useful to you is [litmus](https://litmus.com/)

Getting emails to appear correctly in all the different mail clients is a nightmare, but this is a good tool which will quickly allow you to test your mails before they get sent out.

I believe that they do also have a code editor that if all you are doing is replacing text (I wouldn't recommend a non-programmer tries to do any-more) then this may be sufficient to allow people to instantly see the changes visually.

I think they do also have a few templates available to use and they also allow you to sync your code into mailchimp.